# "image" property inside Article with or without ImageObject?

Tags: google, schema.org, microdata

Can I use `itemprop` `image` directly?:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
<img  itemprop="image" src="1.png">
<h1 itemprop="headline name" >Title of the post</h1>
<div>2016-01-07</div>           
<p itemprop="articleBody">This is the body of the post</p>
</article>
```

Or should I embed inside `ImageObject`?

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
<div itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <img itemprop="contentUrl url" src="1.png" alt="alt of the image">
</div>
<h1 itemprop="headline name" >Title of the post</h1>
<div>2016-01-07</div>           
<p itemprop="articleBody">This is the body of the post</p>
</article>
```

When I use the Google tool (www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/) it gives me the first option.

But then the [testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) gives me an error:

> The attribute image.itemtype has an invalid value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the perspective of Schema.org, both ways are fine, as the [`image` property](http://schema.org/image) expects an [`ImageObject`](http://schema.org/ImageObject) value (your second example) or a [`URL`](http://schema.org/URL) value (your first example).

As always, a specific consumer might support only one of these two ways.

For many of Google’s rich results, an `ImageObject` is required, because Google wants to see more data about the image, which is not possible when providing just a URL. For example, their [Articles rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles) requires the `height`/`width` properties for the `ImageObject` value.

Comment: `<link itemprop="image" href="{{ imgUrl }}">` should work now too as the documentation states for Image: Repeated ImageObject or URL
> The URL to an image that is representative of the article. Only a marked-up image that directly belongs to the article should be specified. Images should be at least 696 pixels wide.